# Getting post value from form created in loop in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need post values from a form created in loop. Here is my view

```
<?php echo form_open('test/'.$id); ?>
   for($i=0;$i<count($array['value']);$i++) 
 <input type="text" name="name[]" value="<?php echo $array['value'][$i]?>" />
<input type="submit" /> 
  <?php }?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

My controller

```
function test ($id)
{ 
    echo $this->input->post('name'),
}
```

This returns an array of values, but I need the value from the id that is submitted.

I need to get variable from array that corresponds to the id eg if i=2 there will be 3 forms if I submit second form the value of second form alone needs to posted, but here I am getting as array

Comment: where you are closing the for loop?

Comment: `print_r($array['value'])` and post the data

Answer (score 0):

View Code could be like this

```
<?php 

foreach($array['value'] as $key=>$value)//for loop was out of php tag
{ 
  echo form_open('controller/test/'.$id);// see controller name here 
 ?>         
   <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $value;?>" />
   <input type="submit" name="submit_<?php echo $key; ?>" /> 
<?php echo form_close(); 
} ?>
```

And Controller code should be

```
function test ($id)
{ 
 echo $id ."<br>";
 echo $this->input->post('name');    
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not what i mean i am having post values as array , i need to get only the value corresponding to id that i am passing to   controller

Comment: @vellaidurai Now it will not come as array see that i am using no array input here... :) 
At least try it once.. and tell  me how its different from your expected output..

Answer (score 0):

create new form for each submit so it will post data of only one form wich you clicked and remove array from name so you can gate value as string instead of array

```
   for($i=0;$i<count($array['value']);$i++) 
      <?php echo form_open('test/'.$id); ?>
      <input type="text" name="name[]" value="<?php echo $array['value'][$i]?>" />
      <input type="submit" /> 
      <?php echo form_close(); ?>
  <?php }?>
```

then you can get as you expected

```
function test ($id)
{ 
    echo $this->input->post('name'),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make three form this way??I haven't tested it but please check this way if that can give you the result:

```
 for($i=0;$i<count($array['value']);$i++) 
  <?php echo form_open('test/'.$id); ?>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $array['value'][$i]?>" />
        <input type="submit" /> 

        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    <?php }?>


//this is controller function 
function test($id) 
 {
    echo $id;
 }
```

Comment: how to get values in controller

Comment: If this is what you are asking then this will give you the result as desired..Please check this,i have tested in my dummy localhost.

Comment: in this case only value of last form will be submitted

Comment: I dont think so because you have three forms with three submit buttons so I guess it submits the form that is being clicked please once you verify this ..

Comment: since name is same for all field , the post value takes the last stored value

Comment: @vellaidurai it is not going to give since i have tested the code..I is going to give the value of the filed whose button is clicked please verify closely.You are getting confused.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111308/discussion-between-sagar-chapagain-and-vellai-durai).